# Trying to pass an array from one class to another

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm new to OOP and i'm trying to get a grasp on it.  What i'm trying to do is return all of the data in the table. There is only 2 rows right now, but i'm not sure how to put all the data in an array and then return it all the way back to the $results variable.

Please help.

```
<?php
include('dates.php');

$events = new dates();
echo $events->getNumberEvents(); <-----returns the number of rows in the table (Works as expected)

$results = $events->getRows(); <------Doesn't work.

?>
```

Dates Class

```
<?php
/********************************************
* Class to connect and get dates from a database 
*********************************************/
require 'phpDatabaseClass.php';

class dates{

    private $db;
    private $arr2 = array();

    /****************************
    * Constructor which creates the $db variable
    ****************************/
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->db = new phpDatabaseClass();
    }   

    /****************************
    * Function which calls the database class and returns the number of rows
    ****************************/
    public function getNumberEvents()
    {   
        $sql = "select count(*) from events";           
        return $this->db->queryNumber($sql);
    }

    /****************************
    * Function which calls the database class and returns the actual rows
    ****************************/
    public function getRows() 
    {
        $sql = "select * from events";

        $this->arr2 = $this->db->queryString($sql);

        foreach($this->arr2 as $key=>$val)
        {
            //$this->arr2 = $val;
            //echo $val;    
        }

    }
}
?>
```

phpDatabaseClass

```
<?php
/********************************************
* Class to connect and query a mysql database 
*********************************************/
require 'config.php';

class phpDatabaseClass {

    private $db;
    private $arr = array();

    /****************************
    * Constructor function which makes the connection to the database
    ****************************/
    public function __construct()
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(PDOexception $e)
        {
            echo 'Can\'t connect to database. Please contact the site administrator';
        }
    }

    /****************************
    * Function which returns the number of rows
    ****************************/
    public function queryNumber($sql)
    {                           
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultsCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        return $resultsCount;
    }


    /****************************
    * Function which returns the data in the rows
    ****************************/
    public function queryString($sql)
    {                           
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($results as $key=>$val)
        {
            $this->arr = $val;
            //echo $this->arr;
        }

        return array($this->arr);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getRows() 
{
    $sql = "select * from events";

    $this->arr2 = $this->db->queryString($sql);
    $return = array();
    foreach($this->arr2 as $key=>$val)
    {
        $return[$key] = $val;  
    }
    return $return;
}
```

That is if you wish to do anything at that stage.  To simply return you can do:

```
return $this->db->queryString($sql);
```

To echo do:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{

    echo $result->fieldname;

}
```

To echo everything do:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.': '.$value;
    }

}
```

The reason for accessing as an object and not an array is that mysqli returns rows as objects.

Comment: If i just return $this->db->queryString($sql), then how do i output all the values? If i do this in my original call: $results = $events->getRows();
         
         foreach($results as $key=>$val) { 
          echo $val;
         }     it only prints out the last column of the first row of data.

Comment: but what if i don't want to echo in the getRows function and i just want to return the results all the way to the original call?

Comment: what is fieldname suppose to be referring to?

Comment: The field from the db you wish to print.  If you do print_r($result) in the foreach loop, it will show you the whole object and you will see the fields there.

Comment: ok using print_r i see that the array contains all the data, but i'm still not sure what to replace fieldname with. the first few fields of the array are [id]=>1 [heading]=>Christmas Party etc.....

Comment: If $result is an array, and you wish echo the heading, you do:
echo $result['heading'];

Comment: That makes sense, but what if i want to echo the entire array though using a foreach loop?

Comment: Updated original.  If that isn't what you want then I am afraid you will have to be far more specific.

Comment: Yep i just figured that out right before you posted it. I'm still unsure why i would have to use a nested foreach loop though. I guess that every row in the data base is returned as it's own array.

Comment: Exactly that, $results is an array of arrays, hence the double foreach.